# Addon development - make visible to Member permissions?

Tags: add-on-development, module, settings

Using EE 3.5.1.

I have made a simple extension to allow a logged in user manage a single `settings()` text field. However, I cannot grant access to this add-on to other Member Groups because it does not appear in the list of addons in the 'Allowed add-on access' list.

[image]

How do I get my addon in this list? I have heard I need to make it into a Module, but Modules don't appear to be able to use the built-in `settings()` function: I get a 404 if I put it in the MCP file so I'm not sure what I'm meant to do.

If anyone other than a Super Admin tries to access the settings page they just get `Error: You are not authorized to access this page`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create as module to display your add-on into the list of the "Allowed add-on access".
You can just echo 'This is just extension.' in the index function of the MCP file of your add-on.